# MongoDB CountAsync and Cursors not working in a Windows Service with the new driver

Tags: c#, windows, mongodb, service

I have a Windows Service that reads data from a SQL Server and write them on MongoDB.

I'm trying to adapt this service to the new MongoDB driver (using 2.0.1 version), but I'm facing some problems.

I have this:

```
 protected void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        threadExternalPage = new Thread(new ThreadStart(FacadeFactory.GetLivePrice.UpdateExternalPage));
```

This code calls this method.

```
 public async void UpdateExternalPage()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            MongoUpdateProductBO mongo = new MongoUpdateProductBO();
            await mongo.UpdateExternalPage();
        }
    }
```

Now the problem: everytime I call this line on mongo.UpdateExternalPage()

```
var count = await collection.CountAsync(new BsonDocument());
```

The method exits without processing the next instructions.

The same thing happens if I execute this line:

```
using (var cursor = await collection.Find(filter).ToCursorAsync())
```

But if I do the same thing using a Windows Forms application, there's no problem! But I need this code working in a Windows Service. Does somebody know if I the implementation is wrong or if there's some restriction using new MongoDB driver?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed the code to the following:

```
 var cursor = collection.Find(filter).ToCursorAsync();
        cursor.Wait();

        using (cursor.Result)
        {
            while (cursor.Result.MoveNextAsync().Result)
            {
```

And it worked as expected.

In the same way, the count works when I change it to:

```
        var temp = collection.CountAsync(new BsonDocument());
        temp.Wait();
        var count = temp.Result;
```

Answer (score 0):

This issue is related to problem with Synchronization context and async/avoid methods.
You have place where you run long running task, this code should be replaced.
[Use one of this approaches for running background task](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/HowToRunBackgroundTasksInASPNET.aspx) described by Scott Hanselman.

You can fast check and at least be sure in source of problem next way:

```
protected void OnStart(string[] args)
{
     ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(async x => await UpdateExternalPage();
}
```

And replace avoid to Task - `public async Task UpdateExternalPage()`.